# how to use log4net in .net core 3.1 to save logs in blob text file

Tags: azure, log4net

I have created webapp using .net core 3.1, used this following link for reference https://github.com/stemarie/log4net.Azure

Now when in .net core i configured log4net.config for saving logs to blob storage but its not working.

can anyone please guide me how to setup .net core for blob storage log saving using log4net?

My log4net.config

```
 <log4net>
    <appender name="AzureAppender2" type="log4net.Appender.AzureBlobAppender">
      <param name="ContainerName" value="{mycontainername}" />
      <param name="DirectoryName" value="logs" />     
      <param name="ConnectionString" value="{storage connection string}" />     
    </appender>

    <!-- Azure AppendBlob Appender, uncomment, set proper BucketName and AWS credentials (appSettings) to try it out -->
    <appender name="AzureAppender4" type="log4net.Appender.AzureAppendBlobAppender">
      <param name="ContainerName" value="{mycontainername}" />
      <param name="DirectoryName" value="logs" />  
      <param name="ConnectionString" value="{storage connection string}" />

    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />   
      <appender-ref ref="AzureAppender2" />     
      <appender-ref ref="AzureAppender4" />    
    </root>
  </log4net>
```